# Java Programming onclickListner not working

Tags: java, android, onclick

**Here is the code:
NewPlanet.java**

```
package chapter.hello.hello_world;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class NewPlanet extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        ImageView marsImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMars);
        marsImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WorldGen mars = new WorldGen("Mars", 642, 3.7);
                mars.setPlanetColonies(1);
                finish();               
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Again 
**Here is code:activity_add.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageEarth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_earth"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageEarth"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_mars"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageVenus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageEarth"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_venus"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageJupiter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageVenus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageMars"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_jupiter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSaturn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageVenus"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_saturn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageNeptune"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageSaturn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageJupiter"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_neptune"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i run emulator when clicking on menu and then to add a planet program suddenly
stops. Plaese help me. I am trying to do this problem using one book Learn Android App
Development by Wallace Jackson.

**Logcat is here**

```
02-23 18:43:44.130: D/gralloc_goldfish(1070): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-23 18:43:47.520: D/dalvikvm(1070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 95K, 6% free 3028K/3204K,        paused 87ms, total 88ms
02-23 18:43:47.530: I/dalvikvm-heap(1070): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.639MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-23 18:43:47.720: D/dalvikvm(1070): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3649K/3828K,   paused 157ms, total 157ms
02-23 18:43:48.650: I/Choreographer(1070): Skipped 142 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 18:43:50.810: D/AndroidRuntime(1070): Shutting down VM
02-23 18:43:50.810: W/dalvikvm(1070): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID: 1070
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class   {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this  activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at  android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 18:43:50.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 18:43:57.670: I/Process(1070): Sending signal. PID: 1070 SIG: 9
02-23 18:50:25.691: D/gralloc_goldfish(1299): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-23 18:50:46.461: D/dalvikvm(1299): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 6% free 3028K/3192K, paused 89ms, total 95ms
02-23 18:50:46.471: I/dalvikvm-heap(1299): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.639MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-23 18:50:46.621: D/dalvikvm(1299): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 3644K/3816K, paused 140ms, total 140ms
02-23 18:50:47.681: I/Choreographer(1299): Skipped 197 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 18:50:48.021: I/Choreographer(1299): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 18:50:49.601: D/AndroidRuntime(1299): Shutting down VM
02-23 18:50:49.631: W/dalvikvm(1299): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID: 1299
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 18:50:49.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 18:50:56.301: I/Process(1299): Sending signal. PID: 1299 SIG: 9
02-23 19:16:39.981: D/gralloc_goldfish(1358): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-23 19:18:55.531: D/dalvikvm(1358): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 6% free 3029K/3196K, paused 88ms, total 97ms
02-23 19:18:55.541: I/dalvikvm-heap(1358): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.640MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-23 19:18:55.621: D/dalvikvm(1358): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 3645K/3820K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
02-23 19:18:56.611: I/Choreographer(1358): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 19:18:58.391: D/AndroidRuntime(1358): Shutting down VM
02-23 19:18:58.391: W/dalvikvm(1358): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID: 1358
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
```

02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    02-23 19:18:58.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-23 19:19:05.861: I/Process(1358): Sending signal. PID: 1358 SIG: 9
    02-23 19:19:24.841: D/gralloc_goldfish(1406): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-23 19:19:26.231: D/dalvikvm(1406): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 6% free 3028K/3200K, paused 96ms, total 102ms
    02-23 19:19:26.241: I/dalvikvm-heap(1406): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.639MB for 635812-byte allocation
    02-23 19:19:26.361: D/dalvikvm(1406): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 3644K/3824K, paused 108ms, total 108ms
    02-23 19:19:27.421: I/Choreographer(1406): Skipped 187 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-23 19:19:29.381: D/AndroidRuntime(1406): Shutting down VM
    02-23 19:19:29.381: W/dalvikvm(1406): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID: 1406
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    02-23 19:19:29.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-23 19:19:35.771: I/Process(1406): Sending signal. PID: 1406 SIG: 9
    02-23 19:22:02.801: D/gralloc_goldfish(1454): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-23 19:22:23.001: D/dalvikvm(1454): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 6% free 3029K/3204K, paused   89ms, total 99ms
    02-23 19:22:23.001: I/dalvikvm-heap(1454): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.640MB for 635812-byte allocation
    02-23 19:22:23.081: D/dalvikvm(1454): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 3645K/3828K, paused 79ms, total 79ms
    02-23 19:22:24.171: I/Choreographer(1454): Skipped 198 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-23 19:22:25.951: D/AndroidRuntime(1454): Shutting down VM
    02-23 19:22:25.951: W/dalvikvm(1454): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID: 1454
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    02-23 19:22:26.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-23 19:27:26.371: I/Process(1454): Sending signal. PID: 1454 SIG: 9
    02-23 19:33:58.111: D/gralloc_goldfish(1505): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    02-23 19:34:00.331: D/dalvikvm(1505): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 95K, 6% free 3028K/3204K, paused 305ms, total 310ms
    02-23 19:34:00.341: I/dalvikvm-heap(1505): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.640MB for 635812-byte allocation
    02-23 19:34:00.491: D/dalvikvm(1505): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 3644K/3828K, paused 123ms, total 123ms
    02-23 19:34:01.651: I/Choreographer(1505): Skipped 232 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-23 19:34:03.711: D/AndroidRuntime(1505): Shutting down VM
    02-23 19:34:03.711: W/dalvikvm(1505): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad6ba8)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): Process: chapter.hello.hello_world, PID:  1505
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: i think you need to put your imageview clickable in xml layout file try this

Comment: Just curious - what does the WorldGen class extend?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you calling `finish()` ?  That will definately make you activity stop

Comment: why on earth are you suggesting that I read a book.  Do you understand what `finish()`.  Maybe you have not explained your problem well enough.

Comment: i also tried without finish() but app stops and says unfortunately hello_world has stoped

Comment: Right, that would produce a logCat error, please show it.

Comment: i think in this program i have to click on mars image then only program will go to app home screen but when i click on add a planet it doesnot open any page it just colse to mobile home screen

Comment: and the error is `19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.hello.hello_world/chapter.hello.hello_world.NewPlanet}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 02-23 19:34:03.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628) `  fix this

Comment: which BTW is at `at chapter.hello.hello_world.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:62)`

Comment: </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="chapter.two.hello_world.NewPlanet" />
        <activity android:name="chapter.two.hello_world.ConfigPlanet" />
        <activity android:name="chapter.two.hello_world.TravelPlanet" />
        <activity android:name="chapter.two.hello_world.AttackPlanet" />

Comment: chapter.hello.hello_world != chapter.two.hello_world

Comment: thank you very much now its running. Actually i am new in java and i have to make one android application so can you please tell me which material is helpful for me..

Comment: I have found `http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html` good.  Glad to that you have got it working.  You may want to accept my answer.